# Luhn Algorithm- Returning True for a False Credit Card

Tags: ruby, luhn

Having a little issue with my code to see if a credit card number adheres to the Luhn Algorithm. The code is returning true when the Credit Card is divisible by 10, but also is returning true when the CC number is not divisible by 10. I have printed out the final sum to make sure the numbers were actually adding to the sum variable, and they seem to be.. Below is my code. I know it can be cleaner, but at this stage I would like to see it work first.

```
def check_card

   c_num= []

   sum=0

   s_numbers=@card_numbers.to_s.reverse.split("")

   s_numbers.each_slice(2) do |x| 
   c_num << (x.last.to_s.to_i*2)
   c_num << (x.first.to_s.to_i)
     end

  c_num.each do |num|
    if num.to_i > 9
      sum+= (num.to_i % 10)+1
    else 
      sum += num.to_i
    end
  end

sum % 10==0 

end
```

Here is how it is being called:

```
it 'returns false for a bad card' do
  card = CreditCard.new(4408041234567892)
  card.check_card.should eq false
end
```

Comment: You code works for me. What is the input you're using?

Comment: hmm..interesting.I am using the following for @card_numbers (4408041234567892), but it produces true.

Comment: Especially interesting, your code gives me false for that number as well.

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code you're using?

Comment: Positive. I have an initialize method above it(for the class), but all it is doing is defining the local variable and sending an ArguementError if the credit card number is not long enough. The sum for the number I sent you keeps coming out to 69, so it should be false..

Comment: You have the sum being printed from within the code? Which line? How are you calling this method?

Comment: The 'sum % 10==0' if I were to change it to 'print sum' I end up getting 69. This means that the argument and code does what it is supposed to do, but for some reason the specs are not coming back correct. Here is how it is being called.

      'it 'returns false for a bad card' do
      card = CreditCard.new(4408041234567892)
      
      card.check_card.should eq false
      end'

Comment: I suspect I know the cause of your problem.  In my answer below, look at the first statement in `def valid?(card)`.  Try using it with your data.

Comment: For future reference, it's often helpful (as it is in this case) to post the code that calls the method, as well as the code of the method itself. Also, if you could post the output of your test (using rspec, I take it?), that would also be helpful.

Comment: 4408041234567893 => true, 440804l234567893 => false.  Those strings are not the same!  Look carefully!  Above you have '2', rather than '3' as the last digit, but in a comment below you have '3'. I assume you mean '3' (and that you're working your way through Rubeque).

Comment: @CarySwoveland The card ending in "2" should be an invalid card, while the one ending in "3" should be valid. That's why those two different numbers are being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your code, commented and adapted to behave like the [wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

```
def check_card(str) #creditcardnumber as argument

   c_num = []

   sum = 0

   s_numbers = str.split("") #no reversing. str.split("").map(&:to_i) would save a lot of to_i's later on...
   checksum = s_numbers.pop.to_i #chop off last digit, store as checksum

   s_numbers.each_slice(2) do |x| 
     c_num << (x.last.to_s.to_i*2)
     c_num << (x.first.to_s.to_i)
   end

  c_num.each do |num|
    if num.to_i > 9
      sum+= (num.to_i % 10)+1
    else 
      sum += num.to_i
    end
  end

  (sum * 9) % 10 == checksum 

end

p check_card("79927398713") #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however the code now says that the argument (4408041234567893) is false-should be true. Also, I see .map(&:to_i) a lot for this problem. Whenever I have seen & it is calling in a Proc or Lambda. What exactly are we doing with the code here.

Comment: Try it with `check_card("4408041234567893")` -  it expects a string. Don't worry about Lambda's and Procs, `map.to_i` would apply the `to_i` method to each element of the array which results from `split("")`: just nice integers to operate on..

Comment: @user2201289 Are you asking about "4408041234567893" or "440804l234567893"?  That cc number is familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Now that another answer has appeared I will offer a suggested coding.  This does not answer your question, but I thought it might be of interest and couldn't very well put it in a comment, because of formatting limitations.

```
def valid?(card)
  return false unless card  =~ /^\d+$/ # Ensure card contains only digits
  arr = card.split('').reverse.each_with_index.map {|d, index| (index.odd? ? 2*(d.to_i) : d.to_i)}
  (arr.join.split('').inject(0) {|tot, d| tot + d.to_i}) % 10 == 0
end 

valid?("1234567890123456") => false
```

Comment: +1 Good Ruby-ish answer. I might suggest that, since you're validating the credit card number, check that it has sixteen digits (or fifteen if it begins with `3`, for AmEx).

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I was just assuming the four major ones use Luhn (and that there'd be no need to check for any that use different lengths).

Comment: @iamnotmaynard  Your suggesion is well-taken. It prompted me to do a minimum of investigation.  This [Wiki](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_card_number) told me more than I ever wanted to know about cc numbers.  It turns out they range from 12 to 19 digits and most, but not all, use Luhn. (This comment replaces an earlier one with that had a bad link.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're confusing the output of the test with the output of the `check_card` method. You've confirmed that `sum == 69`, so `sum % 10 == 0` should return `false` (unless Ruby's math is broken), so your `check_card` method should also return `false` — add the line `puts card.check_card` after the line `card = CreditCard.new(4408041234567892)` (but before the next line) in your testing block to show the value returned.

The next line, `card.check_card.should eq false`, asserts that the returned value "should equal" `false` — that is, it expects `check_card` to be `false` for that value of `@card_numbers`, and will return `true` if that's the case. I suspect that you're seeing the test come up `true` and taking that to mean the method is returning the incorrect value of `true`.

Without seeing the output of the test, this is only speculation, of course. However, your code seems correct and, for me, gives the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

posting my answer because I thought it was clean:

```
def valid?(card_number)
  return false unless card_number !~ /\D/

  card_numbers = card_number.reverse.split("").map(&:to_i)
  sum = 0
  card_numbers.each_with_index do |num, i|
    if i.even?
      sum += num
    else
      sum += (num *= 2) > 9 ? num.divmod(10).inject(:+) : num
    end
  end
  sum % 10 == 0
end
```